# Does the MediaStore Audio ID stay on SD-Card replug?

Tags: android, audio, sd-card, mediastore

For example, I have Music-Files on my SD card with the MediaStore audio_id 25 and 37 and I add them to a Playlist. **Then I remove the SD Card** and logically those two songs aren't show when I take a look in the reloaded playlist again. **Then I plug in the same SD Card again** (without having anything changed).

Do media-files get a new ID every time when the SD-Card is scanned? Or do they get the same ID again because nothing on the card got changed?

**All in all: Will they be shown in the Playlist again?**

Poorly I can't test it, because I have not Device with an SD-Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a rescan will create a different audio_id and your playlist will be empty. A workaround is to export your playlist as an m3u and use an app such as New Playlist Manager which can import this m3u and recreate your original playlist. (I must declare my interest in npm as i am the developer)